# Unable to list changed files in Gitlab pipeline: fatal: ambiguous argument: unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: git, gitlab, git-diff

I am using the following line to collect changed files in my branch

```
git diff --name-only "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"^! | grep ...
```

But getting the following error

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'my/branch^!': unknown revision or path not in the working tree
```

Why and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think GitLab CI checks out the branch, but it instead runs the pipeline in detached HEAD mode. You can try `"origin/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH^!"`, maybe the remote tracking branch is set up and available.

But since the pipeline always checks out the branch, you can simply use `HEAD` to reference the current commit.

Depending on what you want to achieve, the solution might be simple or impossible:

1. "Compare against the default branch of the repo" (usually `main` or `master`): `git diff --name-only "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" HEAD`
2. "Compare against the target of the merge request" (only possible in merge request pipelines): `git diff --name-only "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME"...HEAD` (`...` here takes the merge base of the two commits, consequently showing you the changes since your branch was created, but ignoring any changes made on the target branch)
3. Anything else: likely impossible or very difficult. At least not answerable with the current information given. (And it feels like the question is showing an error, but actually asking about a different use-case. Makes me wonder if this is [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) question)

Comment: What if I do `git diff --name-only "$CI_COMMIT_SHA"^!`? What does `^!` do here?

Comment: Sorry, I was missing `^!` from my answer. [`^!` excludes all parents of the commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_revision_range_summary). But I'm not sure if that makes sense in this context, because it would only select a single commit. Perhaps you meant `commit commit^@`?

Comment: No, even that doesn't make sense. If you want the changes in your branch, you need to compare against your base branch (or merge base if you have a target branch, e.g. when in an MR)

Comment: What is correct syntax to take changes from my branch in context of CI?

Comment: @Dims without a merge request, that's not really answerable, because you don't know against what you are comparing (unless you define some hard-coded "default branch", such as master against which you will always compare). Remember: branches do not exist in Git, they simply name a single commit. The "history" or "changes of a branch" is then implied by following the parent pointers of the commits.

Comment: Once you know against what you are comparing, then simply `git diff $your_target HEAD`